# Calling native async method from custom Xamarin.Forms view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know the recommended approach on calling native APIs from a Xamarin.Forms view is to create an event with the "Requested" name suffix and then handle it from the `Renderer`. This is utilized in the [`ListView` class](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/1a30ab22d0d69bab54d7c3e756ab76064d511636/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ListView.cs#L57) for `ScrollTo` for example.

In my case however, I would like to call a native API which not only **returns data**, but is also **`async`-based.**.

A nice example would be the UWP `WebView` control, which has `InvokeScriptAsync` method, which is asynchronous and returns a `IAsyncOperation<string>`.

If I followed the normal advice directly, I could come up with a delegate like:

```
delegate Task<string> InvokeScriptRequestedHandler();

event InvokeScriptRequestedHandler InvokeScriptRequested;
```

And use the following in the Xamarin.Forms custom view:

```
public async Task<string> InvokeScriptAsync()
{
    var handler = InvokeScriptRequested;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        return await handler.Invoke();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will actually work fine, but it is already quite unusual for an event to return a value, and even more so, if it is a `Task<string>`.

Is there a best practice how to approach such scenario?

Comment: Confused...`InvokeScriptAsync` is not an event so why try to wrap in one? Expose it on the custom Forms' view and call it (via an OnPlatform if necessary).

Comment: Suppose I have a custom WebView control defined in. Net Standard library, how would I call this native UWP WebView method?